# error in PHP and database connection

Tags: php, android, database

Hi I have been following this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/
I am trying to create a row  (part 6) a but i always get the "required field is missing" message

I  even tried downloading the code but no luck

I have made the right database in phpmyadmin as instructed what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Do not use mysql_* functions check php manual for alternatives.

Comment: If that tutorial told you to write your query like that, then you should treat that tutorial as toxic waste: You are now vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and since you haven't shown any of your android-side code and what it's sending, we can't really help you.

Comment: Did you make a POST request with the required parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to submit name, price, and description via POST.

Make a html file with this code and fill in the data and it should work:

```
<form action="create_product.php" method="post" name="submit_data">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br />
Price: <input type="text" name="price" value="" /><br />
Description: <input type="text" name="description" value="" />
</form>
```